# How to enable automaticRepairsPolicy for vmss via terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

I'm trying to enable ["automaticRepairsPolicy"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-automatic-instance-repairs) for my azure VMSS via terraform. I can't find the right option in [azurerm documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_scale_set). Is there another way how to enable it? Maybe by creating a policy or adding an extension?

I'm grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a deprecated resource [azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_scale_set)

As documentation says, rely on one of the below resources::

- [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine_scale_set) for linux VMSS
- [azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scale_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine_scale_set) for windows VMSS

Above resources have `automatic_instance_repair` block where you can set them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for that hint . My search was always bringing me to that deprecated resource and I did not recognize that it is deprecated. Sorry my fault ‍♂️